# Are there any drawbacks to using the normal equation in AR parameter estimation?

Tags: time-series

Is it ok to try and estimate the parameters $c$ and $p$ of a standard AR(1) model of the form

$$
X_t = c+ pX_{t-1} +e_t
$$

solving the normal equation

$$
\Theta = (X^T X)^{-1}X^TY
$$

where $\Theta$ is the parameter vector, $X$ a vector containing the $X_{t-1}$ values and $Y$ the $X_t$ vector?

The $Y$ vector would obviously contain $t-1$ values (the first value removed) so that it would equal $X$ in length. We'd use something like

```
X          Y
NA         1
1          2
2          3
3          4
```

and of course ignore the first row.

In other words, is it wrong to apply this "linear regression with multiple variables" method to a time series method of the AR (perhaps others, ARMA, GARCH, etc) sort?

Since I haven't really seen the normal equation used for this sort of problem I reckon the answer to my question is Yes. A secondary question would then be "Why?" Why isn't this method OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two questions here: using regression for vector autoregression (VAR) is ok. But using normal equations is not very stable, for any regression (at least when there are more than one regressor). Also, in your X here, you would need a column of ones, for the intercept c in your equation.

And if you estimate VAR parameters with more lags, your $X^T X$ matrix is liquely to be near singular. [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) would be better, and it's the method usually employed for [regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Orthogonal_decomposition_methods) (or sometimes [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)).

Comment: You're right about the column of ones. I just ignored it in the example. Why would you say that normal equations are not very stable?

Comment: There is often correlation between regressors (especially between lags of the same time series), but then the X'X matrix is near singular, and estimation is numerically instable (big condition number, hence values have low precision)

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use other time series variables and use linear regression, regressing on lagged values of other variables as well as your dependent variable. This is called a Vectorautoregression (VAR) which is used a lot in macroeconometrics. So this is not wrong.